# Configuring a service (via its provider) to use another service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service which I want to be able to configure by passing in a function for it to use. As long as this function returns something my service can use, it doesn't care how it got the data nor sync/async. Here's a sample of what I'd like to be able to do, but will not work for obvious reasons:

```
.config(function(MyServiceProvider, OtherService) {

  MyServiceProvider.setSomeMethod( OtherService.someMethod );

})
```

That would be awesome, but there doesn't seem to be a way to reference "OtherService" from within the config function. I know this is because `OtherService` could potentially not yet be configured and therefore an instance of it shouldn't exist yet, but then what is a person to do in this circumstance?

Is it *(with angst)* proper to make this association within a run block?

```
.run(function(MyService, OtherService) {

  MyService.setSomeMethod( OtherService.someMethod );

})
```

Comment: You can pass the method name from the other service and bind it in config - pass "someMethod" as methodName and then call `OtherService[methodName]` - although I agree it's frustrating, and definitely something you'd expect a fw with a dicto do.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Good idea, but the service doesn't even know about the other service. I could just as soon do `myService.setSomeMethod(function() { return 'whatever' });`. It just so happens that I want to use another service's method here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [$injector](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/%24injector) service to resolve the dependency at a later time, when the bootstrap has settled.

For instance:

```
angular.module('myApp').config(function(myProvider) {
  myProvider.setMethod('myUberMethod');
});

// Somewhere in myProvider

var theUberMethod, theUberMethodName;

function setMethod(dependencyName) {
  theUberMethodName = dependencyName;
}

function performTheMethod() {
  theUberMethod = theUberMethod || $injector.get(theUberMethodName);

  // Magic

  theUberMethod();
}
```

You might even want to take a look at the *invoke* method of the *$injector*, since that allows you to inject arguments into the function method that got injected.

## Edit

I'll have to explain it better.

The problem you're facing has to do with the fact that the *injection module* isn't initialised at the *config phase*, so you cannot inject services into a config function. Only *providers* are allowed. You'll have to postpone any dependency resolving till after the config phase. This can be done by using the $get function on a provider or by injecting the $injector service and using that to do the resolving.

A function can be registered for dependency injection just like any other object. So providing the provider the name of the function would be enough to let it resolve and execute it at a later time.

```
myApp.provider('myFunctionCallee', function() {

  var self = this;

  return {
    hookMyFunction: function(value /* string: name of the function */ ) {
      self.myFunction = value;
    },
    $get: function($injector) {
      return {
        executeMyFunction: function() {
          return $injector.get(self.myFunction)();  
        }
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Now we'll need a way to inform the injector of the function.

### Example one

This is the easiest ... just register a function (object) directly with the injector. We'll resolve the function by requesting 'myFunction'.

```
myApp.value('myFunction', function() { 
  return 'hello injected function!';
});

myApp.config(function(myFunctionCalleeProvider) {
  myFunctionCalleeProvider.hookMyFunction('myFunction');
});
```

### Example two

This method looks a lot like the previous one. We'll register a function directly, but we'll also inject it in our target service.

```
myApp.value('myFunction', function() {
  return 'hello injected service function 1';
});

myApp.factory('myService', function(myFunction) {
  return {
    myServiceFunction: myFunction
  };
});

myApp.config(function(myFunctionCalleeProvider) {
  myFunctionCalleeProvider.hookMyFunction('myFunction');
});
```

### Example three

Sometimes the previous method is not possible. Maybe the code is written by someone else and he/she didn't have this great vision you have. We can however, expose any function on any injectable object:

```
myApp.factory('myService', function() {
  return {
    // We want to target this beast
    myServiceFunction: function() {
      return 'hello injected service function 2';
    }
  };
});

// Inject the target service here ...
myApp.factory('myFunction', function(myService) {
  // ... and expose the beast.
  return myService.myServiceFunction;
});

myApp.config(function(myFunctionCalleeProvider) {
  myFunctionCalleeProvider.hookMyFunction('myFunction');
});
```

You can see, feel and lick it in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mNtHS4?p=preview).

Comment: This assumes that the configured service expects another service to be involved. It doesn't. It just wants a function and doesn't care what the function does.

Comment: I took this idea a step further and passed the `$injector` to the function I declared in the config function. That allows the person doing the configuring to do whatever they want.

Comment: You misunderstood: functions are objects and therefor injectable.

Comment: I'm probably still misunderstanding then :) Your approach seems to use either a function or a service that is a function.. if you wanted to set the method to `SomeService.someMethod`, you'd be out of luck, right?

Comment: My bad it wasn't clear -- was quite late overhere. Please, have a look at the edit.

Comment: If I'm getting it now, I would have said it like this - "Write an angular component like a service that is a function and set its name (string) when configuring the service." I'm going to update my answer just because I've seen similar questions with no good answers and I want to make sure the solution is clear. Check it out, and if I'm on the right track in my answer, I'll accept your answer as mine is derivative.

Answer (score 1):

Both of these answers are derivative of @null's answer. I'm keeping this here for the sake of completeness and clarity. I don't think this topic has been very well discussed elsewhere and it may be hard to get one's head wrapped around (as has been my case).

In my less favorable second approach below, I use `$q.when()` to wrap the configured function that is the subject here. I would recommend always using that in a case like this so that the configured function can safely be synchronous or asynchronous. To reduce complexity, I'm leaving that out of this first example.

### Create a service and pass the reference to that service by name (string).

Configure the provider using a string name that references another service - which way or may not be the service you are actually try to get to:

```
.config(function(SomeServiceProvider) {
  SomeServiceProvider.someServiceName = 'ThisService';
})
```

`ThisService` is going to be called as a function by `SomeService`. `ThisService` could have multiple other services injected into it, do something with them and return the result.

```
.factory('ThisService', function(FooService, BarService) {
  var service = function() {
    var x = FooService.whatever();
    var y = BarService.blah();
    return x+y;
  };
  return service;
})
```

In `SomeService`, which you configured, use `$injector` to get `ThisService`.

```
.provider('SomeService', [
  function() {

    var config = this;

    this.someServiceName = null;

    this.$get = [
      '$injector',
      factory
    ];

    function factory($injector) {

      var service = function() {
        //do stuff
        //call the configured function
        var fn = $injector.get(config.someServiceName);
        var myData = fn();
        //etc
      };

      return service;

    }

  }
])
```

I'm currently expanding this just a bit by using a default function that will be called if no service name is given in configuration:

```
.provider('SomeService', [
  function() {

    var config = this;

    this.defaultFn = function() {
      //default stuff
    };

    this.someServiceName = null;

    this.$get = [
      '$injector',
      factory
    ];

    function factory($injector) {

      var service = function() {
        //do stuff

        //use defaultFn if no service name was given
        var fn = config.someServiceName
          ? $injector.get(config.someServiceName)
          : config.defaultFn
        ;
        var myData = fn();
        //etc
      };

      return service;

    }

  }
])
```

A slight drawback of this approach is just in that it creates another named angular component (the service), but that's really not a problem, unless you're very bad at naming things or very unlucky. I just appended "Config" to the beginning of the service name to sort of namespace and label it.

### Another Option: Pass $injector to a function created in configuration.

This is my old answer and I favor the above solution instead.

(The use of `$q` here is not relevant to the question. I included it because it is very relevant to the functionality - the configured service can use either sync or async functions.)

```
.config([
  'MyServiceProvider',
  function(MyServiceProvider) {

    MyServiceProvider.setSomeMethod(function($injector) {
      var OtherModule = $injector.get('OtherModule');
      OtherModule.someMethod();
    });

  }
])

.provider('MyService', [
  function() {

    var config = this;

    this.someMethod = function() { };

    this.setSomeMethod = function(fn) {
      this.someMethod = fn;
    };

    this.$get = [
      '$q',
      '$injector',
      factory
    ];

    function factory($q, $injector) {

      var service = function() {
        var loaded = config.someMethod($injector);
        $q.when(loaded).then(function() {

        });
      };

      return service;

    }

  }
])
```